# Gaussian beam reflection derivation

Tags: optics, algebraic-geometry

In this [PhD thesis](https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-f/fd149f5c80b07118f03732f683bd7ee5) I found a good treatment of refraction and reflection of Gaussian beams at a curved surface.
My doubt is from where does it come the cube in the cosine at the denominator of $x^2$ in eq. 4.28 (pag. 58):
$$z_i\approx x_i \tan \theta_i+\frac{x_i^2}{2 R_I \cos^3 \theta_i}+\frac{y_i^2}{2 R_S \cos \theta_i}$$
Following that approach (actually from the paper [*"Reflection and Refraction of Gaussian Light Beams at Tilted Ellipsoidal Surfaces"*](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-8-5-975)) I have to find an approximated solution for z on the ellipsoid of revolution from eq. 4.27:
$$ (x_i+A \sin \theta_i)^2+(A y_i/B)^2+(z_i-A \cos \theta_i)^2=A^2$$
The exact solution is
$$z_i=A \cos \theta_i \pm \sqrt{A^2-(x_i+A \sin \theta_i)^2+(A y_i/B)^2} =\\ = A \cos \theta_i \pm A \cos \theta_i \sqrt{1- \frac{x_i^2+2 A x_i \sin \theta_i+ (A y_i/B)^2}{A^2 \cos^2 \theta_i}}$$
Where the minus solution is to be selected. The first order approximation is then
$$z_i \approx A \cos \theta_i \left( \frac{x_i^2+2A x_i \sin \theta_i+ (A y_i/B)^2}{2 A^2 \cos^2 \theta_i}\right) = x_i \tan \theta_i + \frac{x_i^2}{2 A \cos \theta_i}+ \frac{A y_i^2}{2 B^2 \cos \theta_i}$$
It adds up, except for the $x^2$ term.

Moreover, I don't understand how it gets to eq. 4.31:
$$\psi_r(x_i, y_i)= k_i x_i \tan \theta_i+ \frac{k_i x_i^2}{2} \left( \frac{1}{q_{1r}}+ \frac{1-2 \cos^2 \theta_i}{R_I \cos^3 \theta_i} \right) + \frac{k_i y_i^2}{2} \left( \frac{1}{q_{2r}}+ \frac{1-2 \cos^2 \theta_i}{R_S \cos^3 \theta_i} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the $\cos^3$, my mistake has been of stopping the expansion in x at the first order, but, considering that the variation contains both a linear and a quadratic term.\
Considering that
$$\sqrt{1-\delta} \approx 1 - \frac{\delta}{2}-\frac{\delta^2}{8}+O(\delta^3)$$
it becomes
$$z_i \approx A \cos \theta_i \left[ \frac{1}{2}\frac{2 A x_i \sin \theta_i + x_i^2}{A^2 \cos^2 \theta_i} + \frac{1}{8}\frac{\left(2 A x_i \sin \theta_i + x_i^2 \right)^2}{A^4 \cos^4 \theta_i}  \right] =\\= x_i \tan \theta_i + A \cos \theta_i \left( \frac{x_i^2}{2 A^2 \cos^2 \theta_i} +\frac{4 A^2 \sin^2 \theta_i x_i^2+...}{8 A^4 \cos^4 \theta_i} \right)$$
And one can check that the quadratic term coefficient becomes $1/\cos^3 \theta_i$.

Answer (score 0):

For eq. 4.31, one has to put eq. 4.28 for $z_i$ into $z_r$ of eq. 4.30:
$$z_r= x_i \sin 2 \theta_i - z_i \cos 2 \theta_i= x_i \sin 2 \theta_i - \cos 2 \theta_i \left( x_i \tan \theta_i + \frac{x_i^2}{2 R_I \cos^3 \theta_i} + \frac{y_i^2}{2 R_S \cos theta_i}\right)$$
The linear term comes from reducing
$ 2 \sin \theta_i \cos \theta_i -(2 \cos^2 \theta_i-1) \tan \theta_i$.

For refraction the procedure is the same. In eq. 4.37 the $\cos^2 \theta_t/\cos^2 \theta_i$ in front of $1/q_{1t}$ is because the length parallel to the interface is conserved, so
$$\frac{x_t}{\cos \theta_t}=\frac{x_i}{\cos \theta_i}$$